# Google chrome extension to remove individual cache & cookies from a website?

Tags: chrome, cookies

I am looking for some type of extension on Google Chrome which gives me the ability to remove (permanently), all cookies/cache from a site (for example: google.com) or just the page (google.com/blahbha/videos) or something like that.

I have tried the F-12 option in the dev tools? The problem with it is that you have to keep it open. :( - It's also not permanent.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the browser settings? You can disable cookies on a site, delete cookies every time you exit, block third-party cookies, disable storage apis, etc all directly through the settings.